# Wrapping within filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I am trying to secure my app by checking user permission on all crud actions. Here is one of the examples:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController  
  def create
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    if can_edit(@country)
      @state.save
    else
      redirect_to country_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    if can_edit(@country)
      @state = State.find(params[:id])
      @state.destroy
    else
      redirect_to country_path
    end
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def is_owner?(object)
    current_user == object.user
  end

  def can_edit?(object)
    if logged_in?
      is_owner?(object) || current_user.admin?
    end
  end
end
```

I notice that I have been wrapping `can_edit?` in many controllers. Is there a DRYer way to do this?

Note: All must include an object to check if the logged in user is the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an authorization library. You should look at [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) which allows you to set certain rules about which objects can be accessed by particular users or groups of users.

It has a method, `load_and_authorize_resource`, which you can call in a given controller. So your statues controller would look like:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :country

  def create
    @state.save
  end

  def destroy
    @state = State.find(params[:id])
    @state.destroy
  end
end
```

CanCan will first load the country and determine whether or not the user has the right to view this resource. If not, it will raise an error (which you can rescue in that controller or ApplicationController to return an appropriate response".) You can then access `@country` in any controller action knowing that the user has the right to do so.

Comment: I used CanCan initially, but found that I couldn't customize the error redirection easily, it's not so flexible. So I decided to work on it manually.

Comment: Use the Rails rescue_from method for this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html